# how to convert package-lock.json to yarn.lock?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have an project with `package-lock.json` file.

Now, I want to generate `yarn.lock` file based on `package-lock.json` file or existed `node_modules` of project.

How can I do this? thanks.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use [yarn import](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/import/) to generate `yarn.lock` file from an existing npm-installed `node_modules` folder.

`yarn import` aims to alleviate this challenge by generating a `yarn.lock` file in one of two ways:

1. Using the dependency tree in an existing `package-lock.json` file created by npm install
2. If no such file exists, using the versions found inside `node_modules` according to normal `require.resolve()` resolution rules.

For example:

```
☁  api [develop] ⚡  yarn import   
yarn import v1.17.3
info found npm package-lock.json, converting to yarn.lock
warning jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 21.56s.
```

Comment: command `yarn import`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the tool [synp](https://github.com/imsnif/synp) to convert back and forth:

```
synp --source-file yarn.lock            # will create package-lock.json
synp --source-file package-lock.json    # will create yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

as of yarn 1.7.0 (2018-06-04) you can use `yarn import` to convert npm package-lock.json to yarn.lock instead of having to `npm install` first for node_modules and tell yarn to take a looks at that

> https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/
>
> https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/06/04/yarn-import-package-lock/